# Put the 0 at the same position on two arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts

Sorry for my english, really really tired...

Imagine two arrays:

```
var a = [-10, 5, 0, 5, 10, 15];
var b = [-20, 0, 20, 40, 60, 80];
```

Every value of each array increments by the same number (`a` by 5 and `b` by 20).
I would like to find a way to put the zero on the same position on both arrays.

Keep in mind that:

- each serie has the same number of elements
- you can change the min and max value of each array (the original min and max of a serie have to be a part of the serie, check the example below)
- each value of the array increments by the same number, you can change this value

The expected result could be something like

```
var a = [-10, 5, **0**, 5, 10, 15];
var b = [-60, -30, **0**, 30, 60, 90];
```

`b` increments now by 30 and the original min (-20) and max (8) values are included in the interval.

Any idea on how to do that using javascript?

Why I'd like to do that? To solve something like that:
http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AlignXon2Ys.html

Thanks in advance

Rob

Comment: Hey, what have you tried so far?

Comment: why does the increment change to 30 for `b`?

Comment: Can you change the length of the array?

Comment: @iagowp Nope, you can't change the length of the array ;)

Comment: what should happen if a is `[*, *, *, *, *, 0]` and b is `[0, *, *, *, *, *]`?

Comment: @NinaScholz something like trying to put the zero at the 3rd position

Comment: @NinaScholz  depending on the nature of the data and the min/max of the serie, the range of the data goes to -60 to 90. To have 6 intervals in the chart axis, an increment of 30 is needed.

Comment: please add some more cases and the expected solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The following is a result of code iteration based on comments. Previous code has been removed for clarity, but remains available in edit history.*

This one fixes the zero in the middle of a series, then adjusts values according to the initial requirements. Also rounding to the nearest 5 (previous code was inadequate in that regard, sorry). HTH.

```js
function develop(data) {
  if (data.length < 3) {
    return data;
  }

  var lower = data[0];
  var upper = data[data.length - 1];
  var index = (data.length - 1) / 2;
  var numLeft = Math.floor(index);
  var numRight = Math.ceil(index);
  var leftStep = findStep(lower, numLeft, false);
  var rightStep = findStep(upper, numRight, true);
  var step = roundStep(Math.max(leftStep, rightStep), 5);
  var result = [];
  for (var ii = 0; ii < data.length; ii++) {
    result[ii] = step * (ii - numLeft);
  }
  return result;

  // ---

  function findStep(boundary, numEntries, positive) {
    if (positive && boundary <= 0 || !positive && boundary >= 0) {
      return 1;
    }
    return Math.abs(Math.ceil(boundary / numEntries));
  }

  function roundStep(step, roundTo) {
    if (step < roundTo) {
      return step;
    }
    return Math.ceil(step / roundTo) * roundTo;
  }

}

function test() {
  var testData = [
    [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15],
    [-20, 0, 20, 40, 60, 80],
    [0, 72, 144, 216, 288, 360],
    [-30, -25, -20, -15, -10, 0]
  ];
  var results = [];
  for (var ii = 0; ii < testData.length; ii++) {
    var data = testData[ii];
    results.push(JSON.stringify(data) + " => " + develop(data));
  }
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = results.join("<br>");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="test()" onclick="test()" />
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: doesn't seem right. b[2] = 20 so that array should all increment by 20. Am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: It's the test set of the OP: one series should be fixed, while the other one should be adjusted (shifting the zero, keeping integers, thus requiring a new step).

Comment: right...and the test data b array would shift by 20 to get that array to zero on same index as the a array. That's how i did mine is that your interpretation also

Comment: Hm, not sure about this. I understand the problem as simply generating a new array of integers c, with c[0] <= b[0], c[2]==0 and c[5] >= b[5]. Intermediate values must be filled making sure that the step between numbers remain the same. The new step should be as close as possible as the old step.

Comment: ok..different interpretations. I did it to move y axis on a chart so both index cross zero at same point... so increment moves each element up or down same amount

Comment: @Elegie, thanks for your proposal. Seems not working using this edge case (it should never occour according to the nature of the data): var a = [0, 72, 144, 216, 288, 360], b = [-25, -20, -15, -10, -5, 0];

Comment: @rortelli, please give the wanted solution to the edge case.

Comment: @rortelli As stated, the provided code does not check for the validity of the inputs.Your edge case is not valid in regards of your requirements. One cannot transform b into [0, ? ? ? ? ?] while making sure values remain contained in the new interval, because your pivot (0) is superior to all values. You need to clarify your requirements for such cases - and if this case should not happen, you should simply throw an exception when checking the inputs, and handle it in the right place. HTH.

Comment: @Elegie the solution would be to put the zero in the middle of each array and to adapt the min/max values

Comment: BTW, @Elegie, your solution seems to work. I just have to pay attention to check the 0 position of each array. a1 must be the array having the smallest position.

Comment: @rortelli In your example, you provided two arrays, so I assumed the position of the zero had to be inferred from one of them. But ISTM that you actually want to fix the position of the zero in the middle of each array,  i.e. the arrays are independent?

Comment: @rortelli I've updated the code, fixing the position of the zero. I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but I'm probably doing couple thins not necessary

```
var setIndex = function (arr1, arr2) {
  var arr1Min = arr1[0];
  var arr2Min = arr2[0];
  var arr1Max = arr1[arr1.length-1];
  var arr2Max = arr2[arr2.length-1];
  var length = arr1.length;
  var newRatio;
  var newMin;
  var newMax;

  var ratioArr1 = arr1Max/arr1Min;
  var ratioArr2 = arr2Max/arr2Min;

  if(ratioArr1 < ratioArr2){
    newMin = calcNewMin(arr1Min, arr1Max, ratioArr2);

    newMax = ratioArr2 * newMin;
    newRatio = (newMax - newMin)/(length-1);

    arr1 = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
      arr1.push(newMin + (i * newRatio));
    }
    return [arr1, arr2];

  } else {
    newMin = calcNewMin(arr2Min, arr2Max, ratioArr1);

    newMax = ratioArr1 * newMin;
    newRatio = (newMax - newMin)/(length-1);

    arr2 = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
      arr2.push(newMin + (i * newRatio));
    }
    return [arr1, arr2];
  }
};


var calcNewMin = function(min, max, ratio){
  var count = 1;
  var newMin = min;
  var newMax = max;
  while(newMax <= max){
    count++;
    newMin = min - count;
    newMax = newMin * ratio;
  }
  return newMin;
};
```

Comment: thanks for your try. Take the arrays below. Using a and b it works like a charm. It fails using ac or cd.var a = [-72, 0, 72, 144, 216, 288],
    b = [-158, -79, 0, 79, 158, 237],
    c = [0, 72, 144, 216, 288, 360],
    d = [-30, -25, -20, -15, -10, 0];

Answer (score 0):

Compare the array ranges first, if one array includes the range of the other one then the answer is a series with an increment higher than the array that increments where the start of the range is:

```
0 - increment * (position of 0)
```

In your example:

```
var a = [-10, 5, 0, 5, 10, 15];
var b = [-20, 0, 20, 40, 60, 80];
```

`b` includes the range of `a`, so any series that have an increment higher than `b` and obeys the rules at the beginning are valid solutions to the problem:

```
[-20, 0, 20, 40, 60, 80]
[-21, 0, 21, 42, 63, 84]
[-22, 0, 22, 44, 66, 88]
...
[-60, 0, 60, 120, 180, 240]
```

All of these series include the range of `a`.

It gets a little bit trickier when the ranges overlap:

```
[-10, 0, 10, 20, 30]
[ 0, 20, 40, 60, 80]
```

The idea behind is the same. We'll pick the series with the smallest value:

```
[-10, 0, 10, 20, 30]
```

From this, we'll need to find a higher increment so that it satisfies:

```
start + (inc * length) > max of other series.
```

Where start:

```
0 - (inc * pos of 0 in picked series)
```

Moving stuff around you get:

```
inc > (max value / (length - pos of 0 in picked series))
```

So in this example:

```
inc > 80 / (5 - 2)
inc > 80 / 3
inc > 26.666
```

Lets try it with an increment of 27 and a start of -27:

```
[-27, 0, 27, 54, 81]
```

Now, that you we know how to solve the problem, lets try it with code:

```
function getMinMax(a, b){
    var last = a.length - 1,
        min = a[0] < b[0] ? a : b,
        max = a[last] > b[last] ? a : b;

    return { min : min, max : max };
}

function closestInc(range){
    if(range.min === range.max){
        return range.min[1] - range.min[0];
    } else {
        var last = range.min.length - 1,
            maxValue = range.max[last],
            posOfCero = range.min.indexOf(0);
        return (maxValue/(range.min.length - posOfCero));
    }
}
```

So, all the possible answers would be any series with an increment value bigger than `closestInc(a, b)` and a start of `-closestInc(a,b) * posOfCero`.

Here's a function that prints out all possible values slowly:

```
function createSeries(inc, posOfCero, count) {
  var series = [],
    start = -(inc * posOfCero);

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    series.push(start + (inc * i));
  }

  return series;
}

var a = [-10, 5, 0, 5, 10, 15],
  b = [-20, 0, 20, 40, 60, 80],
  ranges = getMinMax(a, b),
  inc = closestInc(ranges),
  posOfCero = ranges.min.indexOf(0);

setTimeout(function printSeries(i) {
  console.log(createSeries(inc + 1, posOfCero, range.min.length));
  setTimeout(printSeries, 1000, i + 1);
}, 1000, 1);
```

A snippet below:

```js
function getMinMax(a, b) {
  var last = a.length - 1,
      min = a[0] < b[0] ? a : b,
      max = a[last] > b[last] ? a : b;

  return {
    min: min,
    max: max
  };
}

function closestInc(range) {
  if (range.min === range.max) {
    return range.min[1] - range.min[0];
  } else {
    var last = range.min.length - 1,
        maxValue = range.max[last],
        posOfCero = range.min.indexOf(0) + 1;
    return (maxValue / (range.min.length - posOfCero));
  }
}

function createSeries(inc, posOfCero, count) {
  var series = [],
      start = -(inc * posOfCero);

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    series.push(start + (inc * i));
  }

  return series;
}

//var a = [-10, 5, 0, 5, 10, 15],
//    b = [-20, 0, 20, 40, 60, 80],
var a = [-10, 0, 10, 20, 30],
    b = [ 0, 20, 40, 60, 80],
    ranges = getMinMax(a, b),
    inc = closestInc(ranges),
    posOfCero = ranges.min.indexOf(0);

setTimeout(function printSeries(i) {
  console.log(createSeries(Math.round(inc + i), posOfCero, ranges.min.length));
  setTimeout(printSeries, 1000, i + 1);
}, 1000, 1);
```

A last note, this aren't all possible series to match your rules (there might still be some valid increments between the series).

Answer (score -2):

You can use `Array.push` and `Array.unshift` like this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ddq52h6/)